# Dynamics CRM workflow date field

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a workflow that sets the value of a date field at (today + 30 days).

In the appointments form I have a field that shows the remaining time, in days, till the limit set above by the workflow.

The problem is that the value of the datetime field is different if it is set by the workflow or if it set by the user in the form. For example, the value set by the workflow also considers the current time when adding 30 days:

2016-11-09T13:09:48.000

while the datetime value set by the user in the form is something like

2016-11-08T23:00:00.000 (I don't understand why 23) edit: it must be because of UTC-1

What could be a way to tell the workflow that the result of adding 30 days must be in the same format of the date selected by the user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For defining dates in the way I need a workflow is not enough, so a plugin is necessary. I solved my problem in the properties of the date field, by setting "Behaviour" and "Format" to "Only date".